Crear reporte con saldo inicial movimientos del mes y saldo final con MYSQL y Laravel
Tengo dos tablas:
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `cfather` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nature_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL);


   CREATE TABLE `policy_details` (
  `policy_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `account_id` bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `concepto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cargo` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `abono` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_pol` date NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO `accounts` (`id`, `cfather`, `nombre`, `nature_id`) VALUES
(102000000, NULL, 'Bancos', 'D'),
(102001000, 102000000, 'bancos nacionales', 'D'),
(102001001, 102001000, 'Banamex', 'D'),
(102001002, 102001000, 'Bancomer', 'D'),
(102002000, 102000000, 'Bancos extranjeros', 'D'),
(102002001, 102002000, 'Citibank', 'D'),
(102002002, 102002000, 'J P Morgan', 'D'),
(107000000, NULL, 'Deudores diversos', 'D'),
(107001000, 107000000, 'Funcionarios y empleados', 'D'),
(107005000, 107000000, 'Otros deudores diversos', 'D'),
(201000000, NULL, 'Proveedores', 'H'),
(201001000, 201000000, 'Proveedores nacionales', 'H'),
(201002000, 201000000, 'Proveedores extranjeros', 'H'),
(205000000, NULL, 'Acreedores diversos cp', 'H'),
(205001000, 205000000, 'Acreedores diversos cp nal', 'H'),
(205002000, 205000000, 'Acreedores diversos cp ext', 'H'),
(600000000, NULL, 'Gastos', 'D'),
(602000000, 600000000, 'Gastos de venta', 'D'),
(602050000, 602000000, 'Telefono e internet', 'D'),
(602052000, 602000000, 'Energia electrica', 'D'),
(603000000, 600000000, 'Gastos de administración', 'D'),
(603050000, 603000000, 'Telefono e internet', 'D'),
(603052000, 603000000, 'Energia electrica', 'D');

INSERT INTO `policy_details` (`policy_id`, `account_id`, `concepto`, `cargo`, `abono`, `fecha_pol`) VALUES
(1, 102001001, 'Prestamo recibido', 400.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 205001000, 'Prestamo recibido', 0.00, 750.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 102001002, 'Prestamo recibido', 100.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 102002001, 'Prestamo recibido', 200.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(1, 102002002, 'Prestamo recibido', 50.00, 0.00, '2024-01-01'),
(2, 107001000, 'Prestamo a empleado', 20.00, 0.00, '2024-02-07'),
(2, 102001001, 'Prestamo a empleado', 0.00, 20.00, '2024-02-07'),
(3, 603050000, 'Pago telefono', 10.00, 0.00, '2024-03-12'),
(3, 102001002, 'Pago telefono', 0.00, 10.00, '2024-03-12');

El reporte que intento obtener es el siguiente:

Es un reporte que en contabilidan lo conocen como balanza de comprobacion del mes de Marzo de 2024.
El saldo inicial de este reporte se compone de los cargos de enero a febrero menos los abonos de enero a febrero.
El saldo final se compone del saldo inicial, mas los cargos, menos los abonos del mes de marzo.
Con el siguiente codigo obtengo los movimientos del mes de marzo. Lo que no puedo obtener es el saldo inicial, el cual se compone de los cargos menos los abonos de enero a febrero:
WITH RECURSIVE balanza1 AS (

    SELECT a.id as account_id, a.id as balance_account_id FROM accounts AS a 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT a.cfather AS account_id, b1.balance_account_id FROM balanza1 as b1 
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = b1.account_id WHERE a.cfather IS NOT NULL

), balanza2 AS (

    SELECT a.account_id, SUM(pd.cargo) as cargos_marzo, SUM(pd.abono) as abonos_marzo, /*IF(nature_id = 'D', SUM(pd.cargo) - SUM(pd.abono), SUM(pd.abono) - SUM(pd.cargo)) */ SUM(pd.cargo) - SUM(pd.abono) AS final_marzo 
    FROM balanza1 AS a INNER JOIN policy_details AS pd ON pd.account_id = a.balance_account_id 
    WHERE (pd.fecha_pol >= '2024-03-01' AND pd.fecha_pol <= '2024-03-31') 
    GROUP BY a.account_id
)

SELECT a.id, a.nombre, b2.cargos_marzo, b2.abonos_marzo, b2.final_marzo FROM balanza2 AS b2 INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = b2.account_id ORDER BY a.id


Creé la base de datos en mi instacia de MySQL. Y me funcionó esto:

WITH RECURSIVE balanza1 AS (
    SELECT a.id as account_id, a.id as balance_account_id 
    FROM accounts AS a 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT a.cfather AS account_id, b1.balance_account_id 
    FROM balanza1 as b1 
    INNER JOIN accounts AS a ON a.id = b1.account_id 
    WHERE a.cfather IS NOT NULL
), 
movimientos_ene_feb AS (
    SELECT 
        a.account_id, 
        SUM(pd.cargo) AS cargos_ene_feb, 
        SUM(pd.abono) AS abonos_ene_feb, 
        SUM(pd.cargo) - SUM(pd.abono) AS saldo_inicial
    FROM balanza1 AS a 
    INNER JOIN policy_details AS pd 
        ON pd.account_id = a.balance_account_id 
    WHERE pd.fecha_pol >= '2024-01-01' AND pd.fecha_pol <= '2024-02-29' 
    GROUP BY a.account_id
), 
movimientos_mar AS (
    SELECT 
        a.account_id, 
        SUM(pd.cargo) AS cargos_marzo, 
        SUM(pd.abono) AS abonos_marzo
    FROM balanza1 AS a 
    INNER JOIN policy_details AS pd 
        ON pd.account_id = a.balance_account_id 
    WHERE pd.fecha_pol >= '2024-03-01' AND pd.fecha_pol <= '2024-03-31' 
    GROUP BY a.account_id
)
SELECT 
    a.id, 
    a.nombre, 
    COALESCE(ene_feb.saldo_inicial, 0) AS saldo_inicial,
    COALESCE(mar.cargos_marzo, 0) AS cargos_marzo,
    COALESCE(mar.abonos_marzo, 0) AS abonos_marzo,
    COALESCE(ene_feb.saldo_inicial, 0) + COALESCE(mar.cargos_marzo, 0) - COALESCE(mar.abonos_marzo, 0) AS saldo_final_marzo
FROM accounts AS a
LEFT JOIN movimientos_ene_feb AS ene_feb ON a.id = ene_feb.account_id
LEFT JOIN movimientos_mar AS mar ON a.id = mar.account_id
ORDER BY a.id;

La consulta primero crea una estructura jerárquica de cuentas con la cTE balanza1, que recorre recursivamente todas las relaciones padre-hijo en la tabla accounts. Luego, la CTE movimientos_ene_feb calcula los cargos, abonos y el saldo inicial sumando los movimientos de enero y febrero, restando los abonos de los cargos por cuenta.
Después los une con COALESCE para manejar cuentas sin movimientos, y calcula el saldo final de marzo sumando el saldo inicial con los cargos y restando los abonos del mes.

Si me funcionó, muchas gracias por la ayuda!
